# meta description quotes escape

Tags: html, escaping, meta-tags

html code meta tag description,

it is generated dynamically and we have quotes in the description part and  search engines didn't read everything.

it shows until the quotes begins in the search results

how to deal with it ?

thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes using [HTML character references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#entities):

```
<meta name="description" content="&quot;quoted content&quot;">
```

The description here is `"quoted content"`.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP use `strip_tages` + `str_replace('"',"&quot")` to archiv

`<meta name="description" content="&quot;quoted content&quot;">`